# Тире и запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли где-то, кроме прямой речи, ставить запятую перед тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая перед тире ставится в том случае, если перед ним нужно закрыть причастный или деепричестный оборот.
Например: *"Я посмотрел в ту сторону, куда он указывал, - очень красиво!"*

Comment: Я не понял, где здесь причастный или деепричастный оборот.

Answer (score 3):

В ответе нет ни деепричастного, ни причастного оборота! Это определительное придаточное предложение. Пример с причастным оборотом: Лист, падающий с ветки, - последнее напоминание о лете.